# ERROR: Talend S3 - AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header

Tags: amazon-s3, talend

I'm using talend open studio to push salesforce data to my redshift database. By pushing data using the following:

```
1. tSalesforceInput
2. tMap
3. tFileOutputDelimited
4. tRedshiftOutput
```

I am only getting about 2-5 rows/s which does not work at all for me.

By pushing the delimited file to tS3Put and then pushing data to redshift the transfer would go MUCH faster, about 500 rows/s. The issue I continue to face is that I get the error:

AWS authentication requires a valid Date or x-amz-date header (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: CC9C86CCC65625C0

And I have no idea how to solve. I have tried using tLibraryLoad to load joda time 2.8.2 before running and then running after but it still fails. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: which version you're on? The default S3 components have some limits if you want to upload files bigger than 5GB, but other than that it should work fine.
Are you sure the component parameters are right?

Comment: Btw per my measures (gzip compressed data files using client side encryption) the load speed from S3 to redshift was around 20 Mbit/second, which is much more better than 500 row/sec you're targeting.

Comment: I'm trying to upload a 30mb .csv file. I try to simply test the connection using tS3Connect and it fails. When I use tLibraryLoad and load the AWS JAR file it does not give me an error message but it doesn't really do anything...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem using Talend 6.1  The issue is an incompatibility of Java8, the AWS SDK and the joda-time 2.3 library that Talend bundles.

The solution I found was adapted from:  [TalendForge](https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=45695)

Download joda-time 2.8.2 jar from [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases)

Add a tLibraryLoad and point it to the new joda-time jar file you downloaded.

Go to your project's Run tab/Advanced Settings and add an additional JVM argument of:

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/joda-time-2.8.2.jar
```

Comment: thanks Paul. I used the following for joda time before and it did not work:
"-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\xxxxxx\joda time\joda-time-2.8.2-dist.tar\joda-time-2.8.2"

Comment: Yes, that's because Talend has a joda-time 2.3 jar in the path and you need to make sure the 2.8 one is prepended, not appended to the classpath.

Comment: Okay so I put jodatime2.8.2 in my java jdk 65 lib folder and this is what I put but still got an error: -Xbootclasspath/p:C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\lib\joda-time-2.8.2.jar

Comment: 2 things to check:

1 - did you add the tLibraryLoad at the beginning of your flow?

2 - Can you show the complete classpath for your job?  (it's inside the generated <job_name>.bat or <job_name>.sh file?

Comment: Cannot find any .bat or .sh file for my job. I right click the job repository to export the job and the .zip file is not created. Not sure what's going on.